# How to retrieve form data?

Tags: forms

I want to save the value of input data and retrieve it.
I'm new to creating WordPress plugin and I don't know how to get the value from the form. I have seen some plugin development tutorials but I'm unable to develop it properly.
Here is my code:

```
/*
Plugin Name:  My Custorm Form
Plugin URI:   https://abcd.com
Description:  New plugin
Version:      0.1
Author:       RB
*/

function my_plugin_settings()
{
    add_menu_page( 'My Plugin',
                    'myCust Form',
                    'administrator',
                    'insert-my-plugin_bro',
                    'my_plugin_settings_page',
                    'dashicons-translation',
                    '60'
                );  
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_plugin_settings');


function my_plugin_options()
{
    register_setting('my-form-group','user_input_name');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'my_plugin_options');


function my_plugin_settings_page()
{
    echo "<h1>My Plugin Settings</h1>";
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <form  action="options.php" method="post">
        <?php settings_fields('my-form-group'); ?>
            <b>Enter a name to display:</b><br/>
            <input type="text" name="default-image-url" value="" >

            <?php submit_button(); ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. I have modified your code. You could try this:

```
<?php
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_plugin_create_menu');

function my_plugin_create_menu() {

    //create new top-level menu
    add_menu_page( 'My Plugin',
                    'myCust Form',
                    'administrator',
                    'insert-my-plugin_bro',
                    'my_plugin_settings_page',
                    'dashicons-translation',
                    '60'
                );  

    //call register settings function
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_my_plugin_settings' );
}


function register_my_plugin_settings() {
    //register our settings
    register_setting( 'my-plugin-settings-group', 'display_name' );
}

function my_plugin_settings_page() {
?>
<div class="wrap">
<h1>My Plugin Settings</h1>

<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'my-plugin-settings-group' ); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections( 'my-plugin-settings-group' ); ?>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Enter a name to display</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="display_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('display_name') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <?php submit_button(); ?>

</form>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Wordpress also has a documentation for [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages) . It should help you